# Javascript: A function to split an array of objects based on the existence of a specific field in each object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Javascript: A function to split an array of objects based on the existence of a specific field in each object

Need to create sets that include the objects between occurrences of the filtering field & the filtering field to be included in both sets.

Example data source:

```
var source = [
  { a:1, b:2, c: true},
  { d:1, e:2 },
  { x:1, y:2 },
  { q:1, s:2, c: true}, // to be splitted from here and inclusive in both current and next set
  { da:1, eb:2 },
  { aaa:1, bbb:2 },
  { aa:1, bb:2 },
  { xa:1, ya:2 },
  { qa:1, sa:2, c: true} // to be only splitted if its not the last object in array
  ...
]
```

Based on above source, the filtering flag is "c", so output must be as follows:

```
var output = [
  [
    { a:1, b:2, c: true},
    { d:1, e:2 },
    { x:1, y:2 },
    { q:1, s:2, c: true},
  ],
  [
    { q:1, s:2, c: true},
    { da:1, eb:2 },
    { aaa:1, bbb:2 },
    { aa:1, bb:2 },
    { xa:1, ya:2 },
    { qa:1, sa:2, c: true}
  ]
]
```

Here's the code I have, problem is it adds extra output to first index:

```js
const data = [
  { a:1, b:2, c: true},
  { d:1, e:2 },
  { x:1, y:2 },
  { q:1, s:2, c: true},
  { da:1, eb:2 },
  { aaa:1, bbb:2 },
  { aa:1, bb:2 },
  { xa:1, ya:2 },
  { qa:1, sa:2, c: true}
];

var field = 'c';
var output = [];
var currentSet = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  currentSet.push(data[i]);
  if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(field) && i != data.length - 1) {
    output.push(currentSet);
    currentSet = [data[i]];
  }
}

if (currentSet.length > 0) {
  output.push(currentSet);
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Use a loop. Can you show us your attempt, please?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, used it, please refer to updated question.

Comment: Thanks. I think you're only missing `&& i != 0` in that condition in the loop.

Comment: Btw, I would probably use `data[i][field]` instead of `hasOwnProperty` - I presume if the object contained `c: false`, you would not want to split at that location?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the help @Bergi, but for my requirement, i want to split even if the value is falsy, but the key exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the revised version that meets my specific requirement:

```js
const data = [
  { a:1, b:2, c: true},
  { d:1, e:2 },
  { x:1, y:2 },
  { q:1, s:2, c: true},
  { da:1, eb:2 },
  { aaa:1, bbb:2 },
  { aa:1, bb:2 },
  { xa:1, ya:2 },
  { qa:1, sa:2, c: true}
];

var field = 'c';
var output = [];
var currentSet = [];

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  currentSet.push(data[i]);
  if (data[i].hasOwnProperty(field) && i != 0 && i != data.length - 1) {
    output.push(currentSet);
    currentSet = [data[i]];
  }
}

if (currentSet.length > 0) {
  output.push(currentSet);
}

console.log(output);
```